# How much power does the Iranian president have?

Tags: political-system, iran

As we all know, in Iran the supreme leader has the last word over the entire political system; with the president as the second highest leader.

According to the law the president doesn't have the authority to appoint the chief of army or the commander of revolutionary guard.

*But does he control any key departments like the police and normal army?*

*Who is in charge of his personal protection?*

Answer (score 9):

The president of Iran has much less power than a president or prime minister in a democratic country.

The real power in Iran is with the theocratic Assembly of Experts. These are former religious leaders and elected parliament members with long political careers.  They appoint the Supreme Leader and the Guardians Council. The Supreme Leader is in charge of the military and judges. The Guardians Council are experts in Sharia Law and are in charge of the actions by the judiciary. The judiciary appoints the Expediency Discernment Council which approves elected candidates before elections and potential new laws or other actions made by the parliament or president.

The Revolutionary Guard protects the president and the Supreme Leader is in charge of them.

The president can make diktats if they are approved and offer policies to the parliament to vote. He is also the diplomatic leader of the country.

Iran doesn't have departments. "Departments" are tasks of the Congress in the US handed over to the executive for expediency. Iran has its functions of government separated into units, called ministries, similarly. This is constitutional in Iran also.

The main ministries are controlled by Supreme Leader most directly: Judiciary, [Interior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Interior_(Iran)) (more like an elections board) and Intelligence.

The following are ministries appointed by the president:

- Minister of [Agricultural Jihad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Jihad-e-Agriculture_(Iran))
- Minister of Commerce
- Minister of Communication and Information Technology (there are HUGE restrictions, though)
- Minister of Cooperatives
- Minister of Culture and Islamic Guidance
- Minister of Defense and Logistics
- Minister of Economy and Finance Affairs
- Minister of Education
- Minister of Energy
- Minister of Foreign Affairs
- Minister of Health and Medical Education
- Minister of Housing and Urban Development
- Minister of Industries and Mines Supervisor
- Minister of Labour and Social Affairs
- Minister of Petroleum Supervision
- Minister of Roads and Transportation
- Minister of Science, Research, and Technology
- Minister of Welfare and Social Security

(Most about the list and above you can read, plus Vice president ministries, also appointed by the president on the [Wikipedia Iran page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran))

Comment: I don't think this answers the question: what power does the president have?

Comment: @Avi I added some things

Comment: @RazieMah This is much improved. +1

Comment: The answer mentioned many power of the president. Although based on many negative propaganda which claims majority of power is for the supreme leader, but i reckon the president has plenty of powers as well as the swearer named some of them. Good luck